# How to debug .NET embedded js-files in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, .net, webstorm

I'm wondered is it possible to debug .net embedded js files in WebStorm? Because, actually, breakpoints in the real file doesn't work. And .NET WebApplication sends it's own (zipped) content with no references to original file.

How I can debug **js** in that case, using **WebStorm debugger**?

**UPDATE** (for better understanding of the problem). 
So I have file called, for example, *dialog.js*. I set the property "Embedded" for this file in .net project config. I've added assembly declaration for this file. So it behaves like .net assembly. Then I added that assembly with ScriptManager to queue, loaded on a client startup. And in that stage - this file is loaded with the url like *http://site/ScriptResource.axd?d=AC9roCTnD0FDFmh4thoy3kzImrN7wKp9_WVOFcPes0Zzhg1&t=2aaf8bd5/eval/seq/70*. And I'm not able to debug this file with WebStorm - it reasonably says that cannot connect to the file *dialog.js*. Maybe I need to specify/change the naming rules (or rewrite url) of the url for my embedded files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a browser debugger and debug client-side. Chrome and IE9 come with a good one one built-in, and Firefox has a decent one available as a plugin.

> *Yes. I'm pretty experienced with Firebug... But when I met WebStorm IDE, I felt in love. So I want to use JetBrains' debugger, not built-in one. Also I have experience with GWT technology and JetBrains' debugger was very cool (much more better then others). So my intention is to use WebStorm to debug javascript.* – ajukraine

Ok, granted I don't use WebStorm, but from a glance at its abilities it looks like the WebStorm JS debugger is really for pure HTML/JS programs, not server-side code. That said, there's [this little feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/editors/javascript_editor.jsp?ide=webstorm#Debug_Applications_Directly_in_Firefox) that allows you to debug applications directly in Firefox. The example points toward a file, but I would be surprised if it didn't accept a URL as well. Try pointing that toward your server-side .NET application, and you should be able to debug the JS file in question.

Comment: Yes. I'm pretty experienced with Firebug...

But when I met WebStorm IDE, I felt in love. So I want to use JetBrains' debugger, not built-in one. Also I have experience with GWT technology and JetBrains' debugger was very cool (much more better then others). So my intention is to use **WebStorm** to debug javascript.

Comment: @ajukraine .NET files and WebStorm don't go well together. To debug .NET use visual studio.

Comment: @Raynos You're right. But it's not the point of .NET, it's plain JavaScript file, that should be debugged. Maybe someone has experience in that...

Comment: @Randolpho This is exactly what I did with firefox before asking the question, but it failed with embedded files debugging.

You said: 
_it looks like the WebStorm JS debugger is really for pure HTML/JS programs, not server-side code_ .   
Hm... But server produces the pure JS, that I should be able to debug easily - regardless of the back-end I'm using. Today I prefer .NET, tomorrow Common Lisp. But I don't change JS, so I can continue using my favorite IDE and debugger for JavaScript. But sorry... this is slightly another topic :)

Comment: @ajukraine: Well, you could always just export the JS file and load it into your IDE. It will execute the same either way -- it's not like .NET is in the habit of building dynamic .JS files. Keep in mind that it is still likely to be targeted at whatever markup is generated by the server-side page it supports, so you'll probably need to know a bit more than just the .JS file for comfort.

Comment: Yes. The .NET application dynamically changes the file - adding the one line at the end like that **if(typeof(Sys)!=='undefined')Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();**... Maybe in a next project I'll use all the power of the WebStorm :)

Comment: what kind of answer is this?  This doesn't answer his question and I'm trying to do the same thing.  Webstorm ROCKS and blows away any JS debugger, makes firebug look like an ant.  Please someone explain how to get a debug point in webstorm to work with a .net app!

Comment: @CoffeeAddict I agree that WebStorm rocks -- I switched to it last year when I started messing around with Node.js. But WebStorm is going to have trouble debugging a file it doesn't know about. In OP's case, the file is dynamically generated and executed in the browser. The best place to debug is there. That having been said, your case may not be the same. If so, try local or remote debugging: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/debugging-javascript.html

Comment: I figured it out, you don't need to worry about what the underlying web server is (apache, iis, whatever), and you can even debug remote http urls.  All you do is setup the debug config in webstorm to point to the url you are testing for the "path" attribute in the edit configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, you don't need to worry about what the underlying web server is (apache, iis, whatever), and you can even debug remote http urls. All you do is setup the debug config in webstorm to point to the url you are testing for the "path" attribute in the edit configuration.